# Open Chromium with selenium in read-mode

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to be able to get the main text content of a webpage without anything else.
Firefox do this using with the reader view feature. It seems that Chrome haves this as experimental feature. Despite activating the feature from code, the icon doesn't show up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--reader-mode=true")
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-reader-mode")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=chrome_options)
driver

url = "https://www.google.com"
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

The command line information *chrome://version/* in are showing the parameters :

```
Command Line    
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --enable-reader-mode --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --reader-mode=true --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/var/folders/qx/y0sp0wpn5g524st9yn6f3cdm0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.L3pFOZ --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

*chrome://flags/* doesn't show the reader mode activated. Even if I activate it manually and restart, the reader mode icon is not shown in the binaries as well as Chrome on mac.

Is this feature still exists? If yes, how do I use it from selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by this in your question:

---

> My goal is to be able to get the main text content of a webpage
> without anything else

Also I'm not sure that the search page `Google.com` has a reader mode.

The following code is able to toggle the `Reader Mode` on using `selenium` with a `Chrome` browser.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# reference:
# https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:docs/accessibility/browser/reader_mode.md
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-features=ReaderMode")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = "https://www.cnn.com/us/live-news/baldwin-rust-shooting-charges-decision/index.html"
driver.get(url_main)
sleep(60)
driver.quit()
```

Here is a screenshot showing the webpage without the reader icon using  `selenium` with a `Chrome` browser.

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing the webpage with the reader icon using  `selenium` with a `Chrome` browser.'

[image]

---

My development environment is:

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     macOS
Python:       3.9.0
Selenium:     3.141.0
Chromedriver: 109.0.5414.74
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: The reader mode is not shown on many page. That's probably why I missed it. Thanks for your response